# Test whether tuples have the same content

Tags: python

I have to implement a function `cmpT` which should return the following results:

```
>>> cmpT((1, 2), (1, 2))
True
>>> cmpT((1, 2), (2, 1))
True
>>> cmpT((1, 2), (1, 2, 1))
False
>>> cmpT((1, 2), ())
False
```

My Code:

```
 def cmpT(t1, t2): 
    if t1 == t2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It does not give the required output, `cmpT((1, 2), (2, 1))` does not return `True`. What is wrong?

Comment: `(1, 2) == (2, 1)` is False, do you expect True? If so, use sets.

Comment: cmpT((1, 2), (2, 1)) problem it should return True

Comment: Well, comparing two tuples with `==` does not give `True` for `(x,y)` and `(y,x)`,  so you have to think about another (additional) way to compare them. As this is homework, you have to find this way for yourself. I don't understand what you want to know.

Comment: @Felix: "As this is homework, you have to find this way for yourself." Yeah, or someone will just do his homework for him and get upvoted for it. Welcome to SO.

Comment: @Wooble: I know, but that does not stop me from pointing it out ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should check for each element if it is in both lists and the same number of times. The best solution is just sorting.

```py
def cmpT(t1, t2): 
    return sorted(t1) == sorted(t2)
```

Have a look: http://codepad.org/PH6LrAvU

Comment: This works for the original question because the data types in the tuple are comparable. Otherwise it will raise a `TypeError`. For example, it doesn't work with `complex` numbers.

Comment: (I know this adds nothing to the question): I don't think I've ever seen a question with one accepted answer where all other answers have negative votes...

Answer (score -3):

Like in my comment:

```
def cmpT(t1, t2):
    return len(t1) == len(t2) and set(t1) == set(t2)
```

I don't know if it is faster than sorting for large tuples...

Comment: haha, yes, but that's not in the exercise :) same problem with your sorting: (1,2,1) and (1,1,2) will be equal, should they?... ;)

Comment: (1) so is creating a set, (2) I think it should be

Comment: (1) ? (2) yes, I know, that is what the ;) is for

Comment: @steabert: The question title says they have to have the same content. (1,1,2) and (1,2,2) are not the same content if (1,2) and (1,2,1) aren't. "It passes the 4 test cases the OP posted" doesn't mean it's correct; so would a script that explicitly checks for (1,2) and (2,1), etc, and returns False for (1,3) and (3,1).

Comment: With my slightly sarcastic answer, I had hoped to show that it might be nice to properly define the question in the post by explaining what is meant with "the same content". The title indeed suggests what the OP wants, but the actual question is "i need function X which produces these results", which I then took as the actual problem Unfortunately, my attempt clearly failed, I seem to be confusing people with this answer instead of pointing out what I see as a shortcoming in the question.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to compare the content of two sets you have to convert the tuples to sets.

```
>>> a = set((1,2))
>>> b = set((2,1))
>>> a
set([1, 2])
>>> b
set([1, 2])
>>> a==b
True
```

that is:

```
def compT(t1, t2):
    return set(t1) == set(t2)
```

Comment: compareT((1,2,1),(1,2)) will yield True

Comment: oops. you are right. the straight forward solution is to convert the tuples to dictionaries where the elements as keys and the values are the counts of the keys in the tuple. than compare dicts. note very efficient though.

Comment: the straightforward solution is sorting:) see my answer. p.s. I am not the downvoter.

Comment: don't really care about the downvoting. (and I had it coming - for not thinking it through). Sorting is an elegant way indeed.